# Not being able to close the dynamic lightning component

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to create a dynamic lightning component with the help of $A.createComponents.

```
 $A.createComponents([
         ["c:SubmitForApprovalBody",{oppId:recordId}],
         [ "c:SubmitForApprovalFooter", { okLabel : "Confirm"}]            

       ],
       function(components, status){
           console.log('status : '+status);
           if (status === "SUCCESS") {
               modalBody = components[0];
               modalFooter = components[1];                 
               component.find('modalLib').showCustomModal({
                   header: "Submit for Approval",
                   body: modalBody,
                   footer:modalFooter,
                   showCloseButton: false,
                   closeCallback: function() {
                      alert('you decided to close');
                   }
               })
           }
       }
    );
```

The above is fine. And, I want to close the component when the user clicks on the ok button in 
SubmitForApprovalFooter.

I have used the below one in SubmitForApprovalFooter.

```
 ({
     handleOK : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
     }
  })
```

But nothing happens and the component does not disappear.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've faced the same problem you have a few times. The trick is to save the modal promise as an `aura:attribute` on your component.

1. In your component `c:SubmitForApprovalFooter`, create a parameter on the component called `onClickAction` of type `Aura.Action`
2. Set that attribute in your js as `component.get("c.handleModalClose")`
3. In the `handleModalClose` function, get the modal promise parameter and close the modal from the promise. (see below)

```
({
    yourAction : function(component, event, helper) {
        $A.createComponents([
            ["c:SubmitForApprovalBody",{oppId:recordId}],
            //Notice the `onclickAction` being set
            //If you experience issues with this then use component.getReference("c.handleModalClose")
            [ "c:SubmitForApprovalFooter", { okLabel : "Confirm",
                                            "onclickAction":component.get("c.handleModalClose")
                                        }]
          ],
          function(components, status){
              console.log('status : '+status);
              if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                  modalBody = components[0];
                  modalFooter = components[1];
                  //Set a variable containing the promise                 
                    var modalPromise = component.find('modalLib').showCustomModal({
                      header: "Submit for Approval",
                      body: modalBody,
                      footer:modalFooter,
                      showCloseButton: false,
                      closeCallback: function() {
                         alert('you decided to close');
                      }
                  })
                  //Set the modalPromise as an attribute on your component, type is `Object`
                  //So, `<aura:attribute name="modalPromise" type="Object"/>`
                  component.set("v.modalPromise",modalPromise);
              }
          }
       );
    },
    handleModalClose : function(component,event,helper){
        //I use this all the time now, otherwise aura may try to 
        //grab a modal promise that has been destroyed already
        event.stopPropagation();
        var modPromise = component.get("v.modalPromise");
        modPromise.then(function(m){
            m.close();

        });
    }
})
```